# Is the any way to get "token" using some Google cloud java client?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, vaex

I'm trying to implement this https://vaex.io/docs/api.html:

```
df = vaex.open('gs://vaex-data/airlines/us_airline_data_1988_2019.hdf5?token=MAGIC_GOOGLE_TOKEN')
```

I have java and

```json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project_id",
  "private_key_id": "XXX",
  "private_key": "YYY"
  
}
```

other fields were omitted for brevity.

Is there any possibility to get this token somehow using google cloud java clients?

I'm trying this:

```scala
 def getOrCreateInstance(bigQueryCredentialsJson: String,
                          projectId: String): BigQueryClientService = {
    val serviceAccountCredentials: ServiceAccountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bigQueryCredentialsJson.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
    val bigQuery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
      .setCredentials(serviceAccountCredentials)
      .setProjectId(projectId)
      .build()
      .getService

    new BigQueryClientService(bigQuery, projectId, serviceAccountCredentials)
  }
```

it works for sure since

- I can connect to BigQuery using `BigQuery` instance.
- query result is exported to Cloud Storage, so my current account has RWX access to specific Cloud Bucket

My next step is to provide bucket path + accessToken to another internal system.

Here is another method where I try to get AccessToken

```scala
def getAccessToken(): AccessToken = {
    // serviceAccountCredentials were instantiated above
    serviceAccountCredentials.refreshIfExpired() // exception
    serviceAccountCredentials.getAccessToken
  }
```

It throws exception at `refreshIfExpired`

```
Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided."}, iss:bla_bla@datadiscovery-spark-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com
java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided."}, iss: bla_bla@datadiscovery-spark-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:605)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:243)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:240)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$AsyncRefreshResult.executeIfNew(OAuth2Credentials.java:567)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.asyncFetch(OAuth2Credentials.java:206)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refreshIfExpired(OAuth2Credentials.java:177)
```

I have no idea why but this at least started to create AccessToken

```scala
 def getAccessToken(): AccessToken = {
    val scoped = serviceAccountCredentials.createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write")
    scoped.refreshIfExpired()
    scoped.getAccessToken
  }
```

This I don't follow. service account can export BigQuery query result  to cloud storage, but can't get access token to read same data...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Google Auth Library for Java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java)

The following example fetches a Google OAuth Access Token from a service account JSON key file.

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/credentials.json"));
credentials.refreshIfExpired();
AccessToken token = credentials.getAccessToken();
```

Google Cloud authorization is typically specified via the HTTP header **Authorization: bearer TOKEN**. There are other methods such as signed URLs, but HTTP request query parameters are not supported.

Build the HTTP request similar to this example. Replacel the GOOGLE_STORAGE_URL with the REST API URL such as **https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET/o/OBJECT**

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create(GOOGLE_STORAGE_URL))
    .GET()
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
    .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
    HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Consult the API documentation on the API call and parameters:

[Google Cloud Storage REST API Object GET documenation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get)

Note: I recommend using the Google Cloud Storage Java SDK instead of the REST API example I wrote above.

[Cloud Storage client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java)

Comment: What are the imports needed in a java class for this ?

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa - The documentation lists the imports. Refer to this [quickstart](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java#quickstart) and the first link in my post. For answers that are two years old, I would create a new question as details change over time.